# Error en Do While de opción elegida por Scanner

Tags: java

Dan error el toLowerCase y los equals ¿Qué sucede?
Cannot find symbol.

```
do{
    System.out.println("Elija su opción a, b ó s: ");
    Scanner opMenu = new Scanner(System.in);
    //Convertir la letra en minúscula
    opMenu=opMenu.toLowerCase();

    if (opMenu.equals("a")) {
       System.out.println("Has elegido la opción a");
    }
    if (opMenu.equals("b")) {
       System.out.println("Has elegido la opción b");
    }
    if (opMenu.equals("s")) {
       System.out.println("Has elegido la letra s de Salir");
    }
while (!opMenu.equals("a")||!opMenu.equals("b")||!opMenu.equals("s"))
```

Answer (score 2):

Tienes un par de problemas en tu código:

1. `opMenu`, es de tipo `Scanner`, por lo mismo este no tiene el método `toLowerCase()`, el cual pertenece a los objetos de tipo `String`.
2. No estás obteniendo en ningún lado, lo que el usuario escribe por consola con `next()`, método que posee los objetos de tipo `Scanner`.
3. Todas tus variables estás declaradas dentro del `do`, por lo mismo el `while`, no podrá usarlas como expresiones, por lo mismo estás deben de estar declaradas en forma global.
4. Al `do`, le falta su respectiva llave de cierre y el infaltable `;`
5. En la sentencia `while`, aunque pongas s, a o b, siempre se repetirá infinitamente ya que estas preguntando si la opción recibida, es diferente a s, a b, o por otro lado a, que se repita lo que está en la sentencia `do` y esto al elegir cualquiera de las letras siempre será verdadero. En lugar de usar `OR` (`||`), se debe de usar `AND` (`&&`)

---

Con lo anterior tu código quedaría más o menos como el siguiente:

```java
       Scanner opMenu = new Scanner(System.in);
       String texto;
       do{
            System.out.println("Elija su opción a, b ó s: ");
            //Convertir la letra en minúscula
            texto = opMenu.next().toLowerCase();

        if (texto.equals("a")) {
            System.out.println("Has elegido la opción a");
        }
        if (texto.equals("b")) {
            System.out.println("Has elegido la opción b");
        }
        if (texto.equals("s")) {
            System.out.println("Has elegido la letra s de Salir");
        }
        }while (!texto.equals("a")&&!texto.equals("b")&&!texto.equals("s"));
```

Answer (score 1):

El error que recibes es porque una variable `Scanner` no puede ser tratada como una cadena, en todo caso para poder pedir que se ingrese un valor (En este caso *String*) debes utilizar `opMenu.next()`, otro problema que encontre es que no cerraste el `do` faltando asi la llave `}` y finalmente tu código funcionaria mejor si sacas el `Scanner fuera` de la siguiente forma:

```
Scanner opMenu = new Scanner(System.in);
String opcion = "";
do {
    System.out.println("Elija su opción a, b ó s: ");
    opcion = opMenu.next();

    //Convertir la letra en minúscula
    opcion=opcion.toLowerCase();

    if (opcion.equals("a")) {
       System.out.println("Has elegido la opción a");
    }
    if (opcion.equals("b")) {
       System.out.println("Has elegido la opción b");
    }
    if (opcion.equals("s")) {
       System.out.println("Has elegido la letra s de Salir");
    }
} while (!opcion.equals("a")||!opcion.equals("b")||!opcion.equals("s"));
```

Espero te sirva. Saludos ;)

Answer (score 1):

Antes que todo tienes varios errores de sintaxis.

1 - Te falta la llave de cierre del bloque del `do`.

2 - Te falta el `;` luego del `while`.

Luego, estás llamando al método `toLowerCase` que pertenece a la clase `String` sobre un objeto de tipo `Scanner`.

Imagino que lo que quieres es obtener la opción y luego llevarla a minúscula, por lo que debes antes llamar al método `nextLine()` sobre el objeto `Scanner` y luego si llamar al `toLowerCase()`. Todo esto lo debes almacener en una variable de tipo `String`.

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
//Convertir la letra en minúscula
String opMenu = scanner.nextLine().toLowerCase();
```

El problema de acceso a la variable `opMenu` en el `while` es que dicha variable solo existe dentro del ámbito del bloque `do` por tanto es inaccesible fuera de este bloque.

Por otra parte, el `while` tal y como lo tienes siempre va a evaluarse a `true`, porque estás preguntando si el texto introducido es diferente de a o de b o de s. Así que aunque el texto sea de una de estas opciones siempre va a ser diferente de las otras. Esto se soluciona simplemente usando un `&&`.

El código completo debe quedar así:

```
    String opMenu = "";
    do{
        System.out.println("Elija su opción a, b ó s: ");
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        //Convertir la letra en minúscula
        opMenu = scanner.nextLine().toLowerCase();

        if (opMenu.equals("a")) {
            System.out.println("Has elegido la opción a");
        }
        if (opMenu.equals("b")) {
            System.out.println("Has elegido la opción b");
        }
        if (opMenu.equals("s")) {
            System.out.println("Has elegido la letra s de Salir");
        }
    } while (!opMenu.equals("a") && !opMenu.equals("b") && !opMenu.equals("s"));
```